# How to prevent journald from writing to console?

Tags: centos, systemd-journald

[image]

When I check my Centos Stream 9 console, I see messages written by journald to the console even before logging in. Above are some example messages.

How can I prevent journald from witing ANY message to console terminal?

I tried editing `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` as such and restarted systemd-journald, but there was no difference:

```
ForwardToConsole=no
ForwardToWall=no
```

Comment: What applications are you talking about? And what do you mean by `Centos console`? Is the output you get when the system boots up?

Comment: "Note that I want to make a system wide suppression"   whole_system 2> universe_file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185820/449392

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I narrowed up and edited my question. The main issue is with journald.

Comment: @gapsf thanks, tied this but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is GRUB option for kernel to do that - "splash" - which goes graphic and gives no text. But then you will lose all info, not only errors.